# Hillshade is not showing relief in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d-analyst, hillshade

[image]

When I use the hillshade tool this is what the map looks like. The shaded relief is not showing what it should.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You haven't provided any information that would help us answer your question. Raster details, hillshade tool parameter values etc...

Answer (score 1):

This is caused when the source DEM is in a geographic coordinate system rather than a projected coordinate system. The solution is to project the source DEM to a projected coordinate system (e.g. UTM) and rerun the hillshade.